# Port not responding to telnet

Tags: suse, telnet

I am wondering is the port correctly setup in my Suse linux if it is showing this?
I need to access port 30015 from another host, but at present it is able to ping the host but not able to connect to the port.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 21229 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep 30015 
That is the output

Comment: Actually the port is not for FTP purposes, it is a required port by an application that I am installing on windows server and I installed the database on suse.

Comment: Login to soldb and do either of the following   `telnet soldb 30015` or `nc -v soldb 30015`

Comment: Also this netstat -tlnp | grep 30015

Answer (score 2):

From the `netstat` screenshot you shared , it seems `Port 30015` is listening in TCP mode. Now to check the connectivity , you can use `telnet` or `nc` command

```
    telnet  <hostname>  30015 
           or 
    nc -v <hostname> 30015
```

For example , I am checking for Port 22

```
     nc -v localhost 22
     Connection to localhost 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
     SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

If you are getting "Connection refused" message , check for firewall on destination server.

You can use below command to check firewall rules

```
       iptables -L -n (as root)
```

If `iptables` is blocking the connection , disable `iptables` using below command or add new rules to allow `SSH`

Disabling Iptables

```
  service iptables stop ; chkconfig iptables off
```

Adding rules to allow SSH

```
 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It is worth noting that OpenSuse has a firewall/iptables frontend. If it is enabled, iptables should not be used directly for modifying rules as the firewall will overwrite changes.

Comment: When i telnet from the windows, I am unable to .. please see my original question updated with more screenshots.

Comment: I just replied as comments to your original description